# Why sed do more that I asked?

Tags: linux, sed

When I applied `sed -i -e "s/..\///" -e "s/type_properties\///" testfile` to the following file:

```
#include "../../../../include/concepts/type_properties/operations/has_or_op_v.hpp"

int main() {
    // Test has_not_op_v.
}
```

It output this:

```
#include "../../../include/concepts/operations/has_or_op_v.hpp"

int main() {
  / Test has_not_op_v.
}
```

I just wanted sed to delete one `../` and delete `type_properties/`, but it also spoiled my annoation.

Comment: Escape your `..\/` -> `\.\.\/`

Comment: "More than you asked"? You asked it to remove, on every line, the first instance of a slash preceded by two characters. It saw `␣␣/` (with `␣` representing a space), and duly removed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The character `.` is a *metacharacter*. This means that it has a special meaning. `.` means "match any single letter or character." You want to only match literal `.` characters.

If you change `.` to `\.`, you will get the correct output.

Example:

```
sed -i -e "s/..\///" -e "s/type_properties\///" testfile
```

becomes:

```
sed -i -e "s/\.\.\///" -e "s/type_properties\///" testfile
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, don't use `sed -i` when testing things out. Run without `-i` first and examine the result. When you know it looks right *then* add `-i` to commit the change to the file in-place.

The reason `sed` seems to do more than what it's asked to do is that the comment in the `main()` function matches the first of your two expressions, `..\/` (two characters and a slash).

If you know you'd like to only apply you change to lines starting with `#include`, then you may use

```
sed -e '/^#include/{s%\.\./%%; s%type_properties/%%;}' file.c
```

Here, the two substitutions are performed only on lines starting with the string `#include`.  I've also properly escaped the two dots in the first expression so that they match dots, not "any character".  Since the text that we're matching contains slashes, I've also opted for using an alternative delimiter, `%`, in the `s` commands.